# IS there any way to add an alias to the user Documents folder inside a DMG

Tags: macos, installation, dmg

It is easy enough to add an alias to the `Applications` folder inside a DMG as it is at `/Applications` on every Mac. But is it possible to add an alias to a user's `Documents` folder, where the `Documents` folder has a different path for each user? I tried adding an alias to `~/Documents`, but it became an alias to `/Users/andyb/Documents`, which obviously won't work on anyone else's machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a symbolic link to the users Documents directory since you don't know the path. The '~' as an abbreviation to the home directory cannot be used in a symbolic link because there's no shell that would resolve it.

Alias Files can only be created by the Finder (there's no API for that in Mac OS X), so if an Alias File from the Finder is not working, then there's no way.

I'm afraid, the answer is no.